# ViewPager using FragmentPagerAdapter lagging while swiping

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a ViewPager that uses a FragmentPagerAdapter. I'm using images of size 2048 * 1536 to display in the ViewPager.

When I swipe the ViewPager, it is lagging little bit. 
Am I doing anything wrong here that causes the lag ?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 6;
    ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static final String[] IMAGE_NAME = 
    {"image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
        imageFragmentPagerAdapter = 
        new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
    }

    public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
            return SwipeFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            int position = bundle.getInt("position");
            String imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[position];
            int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", 
                              "com.viewpager.viewpagerusingfragmentpageradapter");
            imageView.setImageResource(imgResId);
            return swipeView;
        }

        static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
            SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return swipeFragment;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewPager lags on swipe because of the size of images you have used in your Fragments. Reduce the size of your images and scale them down to the size of your Fragment. This will reduce the memory consumption from your app and your ViewPager will stop lagging.

To reduce the size of images change the inSampleSize of each image. If inSampleSize is set to a value > 1 then the decoder subsamples the original image and returns you a smaller image to save memory. inSampleSize can be found in BitmapFactory.Options

Go to the following link for more details on this :-

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

If your images still lags you can scale them down further by help of

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

method.